# Automatic logout after verifying transaction is inactive Java Enterprise Web Application

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, logout, auto

I am trying to do Automatic Logout after some specified time from web.xml with below details in EJB Web application.

```xml
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

But for some reason, this is not working.
Can you please suggest if any other configurations needs to be done to make it work?

How can we determine is there any active transactions in applications from code level in EJB Web application.?

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by **Automatic Logout**?

Comment: Logout should happen after specified time Eg: after 30 mins, logout should happen automatically from application by avoiding user to do logout from application by clicking on logout button.